# Laravel Eloquent Results Not coming in find all query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I created a Laravel Eloquent Query With all

```
$result = Model::all()
```

but when it returns only empty object return as result records are there in the table

[image: response image as below]

Comment: Could you share a part of the code?

Comment: I used var_dump() instead of dd() and its worked thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I used

```
 var_dump();die;
```

instead of

```
 dd();
```

the result coming perfectly it is something with the

```
 dd();
```

display